# Kohana 3 Auth in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

Kohana Auth is not validating in IE.  I have read some stuff from discussions on v.2 about changing from user_agent to user_ip... presumably in the ORM file in the AUTH module, how ever this is not resolving my issue.

Another post on v.2 suggest using this

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

/**
 * @package Session
 *
 * Session driver name.
 */
$config['driver'] = 'native';

/**
 * Number of page loads before the session id is regenerated.
 * A value of 0 will disable automatic session id regeneration.
 */
$config['regenerate'] = 0;


// KLUDGE: Windows XP SP3 running IE-7 and 8
// http://bit.ly/gPcV67
$config['validate'] = array('ip_address');
```

They do not mention where to use this at however.

We found this kind of late in testing (where is that thread about the lack of importance of software engineering in school?) and are pretty locked into using AUTH at this point.  I have been beating my head against a wall for hours over this and have gotten virtually no where.

Please HELP!
Thank you,
-David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** - I noticed you were talking about Kohana 3/3.1 after you accepted my answer. Sorry for giving you the wrong information. Glad you got the answer in the end.

---

That code you pasted is from a configuration file. You need to put the content in a file called `session.php` in your config directory.

Have a look at the full configuration file from the source code: http://source.kohanaframework.org/svn/kohana2/trunk/system/config/session.php

Double check the domain in your cookie configuration file too.

If that doesn't work then you might need to clear all the temporary internet data from IE so you know you're working on a clean slate.

Comment: I keep getting this error with both the config from the link you posted and the one I found.


ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Argument 2 passed to Kohana_Arr::merge() must be an array, integer given, called in system/classes/kohana/config/file.php on line 53 and defined

Comment: Never mind, I got it.  The final solution is as bellow, but you pointed me in the right direction, so I gave you credit for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    return array(
      'cookie' => array(
          'name' => 'session_cookie',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'native' => array(
          'name' => 'session_native',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'database' => array(
          'name' => 'session_database',
          'group' => 'default',
          'table' => 'sessions',
      ),
  );

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Where does this go? I'm coming across the same thing right now.