# Kohana 3 Auth in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, kohana, kohana-3, authentication, kohana-auth

I'm finding I can't log in to my Kohana site through IE. (just IE, works fine everywhere else)

It's validating, so much as, it knows if you get your username and password wrong, but its not creating the session.

I've added to: application/config/session.php

```
<?php 
return array(
  'cookie' => array(
      'name' => 'session_cookie',
      'encrypted' => TRUE,
      'lifetime' => 43200,
  ),
  'native' => array(
      'name' => 'session_native',
      'encrypted' => TRUE,
      'lifetime' => 43200,
  ),
  'database' => array(
      'name' => 'session_database',
      'group' => 'default',
      'table' => 'sessions',
  ),
);
```

But I wouldn't expect it to do anything on its own.

Does anyone have any helpful pointers?

I want to re-instate this question as its not really answered in a way that will be helpful to others:
[Kohana 3 Auth in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623139/kohana-3-auth-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it was the fact that there was an underscore in the url!!..
Who'd have thought!. IE can't handle cookies and sessions if there is an underscore in the url.

Don't we all just LOVE ie!! :)

Comment: Stated more plainly, Internet Explorer refuses to create a cookie if there's an underscore in the HOSTNAME. This is a historical limitation based on the fact that underscores aren't valid DNS characters.

Answer (score 0):

Check your *session/cookies options* on your browser. *(IE8 on XP)*
Follow those steps:

```
Tools --> Internet Options --> Privacy --> Advanced.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, nope, thats not it. They are set to accept all.