# Kohana 3.3 - Sessions not set in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, kohana, kohana-3

Having an issue with Sessions not being set in Kohana.

Situation overview:

- Kohana 3.3
- PHP 5.3.x
- Using database sessions
- Chrome, Firefox, Safari(OSX)
  are all working correctly.
- Internet explorer- sessions are not being set- on versions 8-10 (testing with dev tools emulation)
- Session is not even created in the database, which also happens when no encryption key is set (coincidence?)
- Possible curveball- Server is behind a load balancer.  Persistence is on and working, and this is actually the only server behind that load balancer so persistence is an unlikely culprit.

I've dug through the code a little, but cant find anything that would cause this to be an issue just for IE.

There are no [dreaded underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770893/kohana-3-auth-in-ie?rq=1) anywhere in the URL or hostname, and regardless of what I set the `Cookie::$domain` to, the result is the same.

**session.php** settings file:

```
return array(
    'native' => array(
        'name' => 'session_native',
        'lifetime' => 43200,
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
    ),
    'cookie' => array(
        'name' => 'session_cookie',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'database' => array(
        'name' => 'session_database',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
        'group' => 'default',
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
        'gc' => 500,
    ),
);
```

Have set `Session::$default = 'database';`, though doesn't seem to be related to the IE-only issue.  Have also tested with `native` sessions, same result.

Any thoughts or insights?  Feel like I'm missing something completely obvious

Comment: Does it work if you set `Session::$default = 'native';`?  Knowing that will help narrow down where to look.

Comment: It does not.  I should have included that- I will edit original post.

Comment: Use a tool like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to capture the HTTP headers for the request - for both IE and any working browser, and look for the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers.  Let us know what you find. (You can post complete headers in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) - anonymize them first if you think it's necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, was finally able to solve playing with IE's security settings.

Comment: We don't do `[SOLVED]` in the title here. If you've answered your own questions, either post the answer and accept it, or delete the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Turned out to be a missing Compact privacy policy.  IE had stricter privacy settings by default, adding the below header fixed the issue (not ideal but doesn't require making an entire P3P file).

```
/**
 * Added for P3P cookie support
 */
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```